# An entitiy with at least one weak entity

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have the following design:

There is a list of parents in my database. A parent should have at least one child,  and a child must belong to a parent (forget about the husband/wife relations).
(a child is a weak entity)

(No need to add rules for deletion/ update)

How can I achieve this?

I write SQL but I have the problems:

```
Create Table Parent(
  parentName Varchar(255),
  -- Should a parent have an entity named child?
  -- But a parent can have more than one child
  PRIMARY KEY(parentName)
);

Create Table Child(
 parentName varchar(255),
 name varchar(255),
 PRIMARY KEY(parentName, name),
 FOREIGN KEY (parentName) References Parent(parentName));
```

I'm assuming that I have the following error:

- A parent should not exist without a child. However, I could not manage to maintain this.

As an example

parent 1, child1

parent 1, child2

parent 2, child2 --Not allowed!

parent 3, null  -- Not allowed!

null, child 4 -- Not allowed!

Also, I need a child for other relations as well. So, in my opinion, combining child entity with a relation in a table is not a good solution for me.

Comment: Apart from your questions, what if a parent has the same name? It will result in a PK error. Also, what if  parent and child have the same name? You would get a constraint error on the PK on child. An identity int column could fix that. Are you using sql-server or mysql?

Comment: I have simplified the design. Those questions and errors are not the main issues of my problem. I have unique id's and I will create a table with ids. This design is just a simplified illustration of my database.

Comment: Check out Joe Celko and Trees in SQL - that might be of help! Upvote for a very good first question! p.s. welcome to the forum - but please, try and choose a nicer handle! :-)

Comment: I didn't mean to offend anyone :) I was just explaining my problem in details

Comment: I think it's enough make `Child.name` UNIQUE. NULLs not allowed because all fields are members of PKs.

Comment: Is the question for SQL Server or MySQL? Or open to any other DBMS?

Comment: it is MySQL as database

Answer (score -1):

As was mentioned in the comments, there could be name duplicates. It's better to have an `id` column in each table.

Second, adding `NOT NULL` constraint on the foreign key will enforce the rule that each child can have only one parent

```
Create Table Parent(
  id int NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  parentName Varchar(255),
  -- Should a parent have an entity named child? -- No.
  -- But a parent can have more than one child
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

Create Table Child(
 id int NOT NULL UNIQUE,
 parent_id int NOT NULL, -- NOT NULL - each child has a parent
 name varchar(255),
 PRIMARY KEY(id),
 FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) References Parent(id)
);
```

There's only one parent_id field, so each child has no more than one parent

Because each child can have only one parent (one-to-many) relationship, the two-table solution works.

When you have many-to-many relationship, you need a relationship table that contains foreign keys to both tables that represent entities in this relationship.

You might also want to add another `UNIQUE` to `(parent_id, name)` combination, to prevent one parent have multiple children with the same name. (Though, I have heard that some celebrity named all his sons "George")

You can't really enforce that each parent has at least one child, because then you wouldn't be able to add new parents to your database. Current process is:

1. insert a parent
2. insert that parent's children

You can't insert children first, because the constraints will prevent the insert of a child without a parent already existing.

Comment: How does adding IDs solve the UNIQUEness problem/constraint?

Comment: It helps with the problem of multiple parents having the same name

Comment: Oh ok. But I don't see such a problem discussed in the question (only some mention in comments). The question clearly states `PRIMARY KEY(parentName)`, so you can assume for your answer that this constraints holds.

Comment: Anothrer issue with your answer: **"-- UNIQUE -each child has no more than one parent"**. That UNIQUE enforces that each parent has no more than 1 child, not what you claim.

Comment: Yes, constraint holds, but `... what if a parent has the same name? It will result in a PK error`

Comment: `parent_id int NOT NULL UNIQUE` in `Child` table means that `parent_id` is unique within `Child` table, meaning that no two rows in `Child` table have same `parent_id`.... oops, you are right! Fixing.